# What response type is better to return from reactive endpoint if we return multiple objects?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor

If we use reactive approach in Spring we can return Flux/Mono type in methods. So in controller it's good to wrap response ResponseEntity and return it and in case of endpoints which return one object we can write in reactive next code:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/to-do/{toDoId}", produces = {
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE})
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<ToDo>> getToDo(@Valid @PathVariable Long toDoId) {
        return repository.findById(toDoId)
                .map(ResponseEntity::ok);
    }
```

But what if we want to return Flux? After some experiments I found this solution:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/to-do", produces = {
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<Flux<ToDo>> getToDos() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(
                repository.findAll()
        );
    }
```

But if I understand correct here in such format, response like `ResponseEntity<Flux<ToDo>>` will be blocking? So it's better to do something like `<Flux<ResponseEntity<ToDo>>` ? If it's so, how to get it? I should subscribe?

Comment: `<Flux<ResponseEntity<ToDo>>` will get wrapped in a `Response` object when returned. So you are basically either streaming a bunch of ToDo objects or just streaming a bunch or ResponseObjects that are containing ToDos. Why even return a ResponseEntity object if you dont really customize anything in the response?

Comment: `ResponseEntity<Flux<ToDo>> will be blocking?` eh no? Whats your source to this strange statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you don't really use the `ResponseEntity` to customize the reponse status so, why not just return Mono or Flux?

```
@GetMapping(value = "/to-do/{toDoId}", produces = {
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE})
    public Mono<ToDo> getToDo(@Valid @PathVariable Long toDoId) {
        return repository.findById(toDoId);
    }

@GetMapping(value = "/to-do", produces = {
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE})
    public Flux<ToDo> getToDos() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }
```

In any case, [according to the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-ann-responseentity) it's perfectly fine to return ResponseEntity<Mono> and ResponseEntity<Flux>, both will provide an asynchronous, non-blocking response:

> ResponseEntity<Mono> or ResponseEntity<Flux> make the response
> status and headers known immediately while the body is provided
> asynchronously at a later point. Use Mono if the body consists of 0..1
> values or Flux if it can produce multiple values.

Comment: this is what I wanted to know. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can return value using `ResponseEntity` from your reactive controller:

**Publisher can be Mono or Flux**

- `ResponseEntity<Publisher<T>>` - this makes the response status and headers known immediately while the body is provided asynchronously at some later point of time.
- `Publisher<ResponseEntity<T>>` - this provides all three: response
  status, headers, and body, asynchronously at some later point of time. It allows
  the headers and response status to vary depending on the outcome of
  asynchronous handling.

Also it is possible to use the following construct, less common, though:

- `Mono<ResponseEntity<Publisher<T>>>` - provide the response status and headers asynchronously first, and later response body, also asynchronously